# java cannot load error

Tags: java, batch-file, path, classpath

I know this has a stickied thread, but I followed it, and I really don't understand what's wrong.

ultimately, I'm just trying to make a batch file to run Coordinator and then a bunch of Worker.

bla bla bla, it was answered, I took down the pic, was more me having the wrong thing in path, it seems.

Comment: Please take sometime to learn basics of Java. Before you run, you must compile your Java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run you class file, you must compile the java file. The steps are as follows:

### 1 complile the java file

`javac Work.java`

### 2 if there is no error in previous step,please run class file

`java -cp .;%cd%  Work`

Comment: That was part of the error, probably, since I'm using an ide, I dont usually use javac. Also I actually had the jre in my path not the jdk, thanks for your help!